# How google task can connect or hit the internal ip of my machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-tasks, gcp-vpc-firewall

I have created a google cloud task which gets the URL from my program the URL has internal IP and the contents of my program. I want to hit an internal IP with google task the internal IP cannot be accessed without a VPN but all my Machines are on same VPC network so they can communicate with each other. So is there a list of IP address that google task uses which I can whitelist on my firewall so that it can connect to the machine or any other method

Kindly help me please.

I want google cloud task to connect to my VM internal IP address

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Task can only call public IPs. So, directly and out of the box, you can't.

However, you can create a proxy service (Cloud Run or Cloud Functions) that receives the HTTP requests from Cloud Task and forward them to your VPC. For that, you need a [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) (or a new option with Cloud Run: [direct VPC egress](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/vpc-direct-vpc)).

In term of security you can use one of these 2 solutions (or use both if you want)

- Set a secure connection to your proxy service (no allow unauthenticated) and add [OIDC authentication in Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token)
- Set the ingress of the [proxy service to "internal"](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress). Cloud Task can set HTTP request authenticated as coming from Google internal network (it's not a VPC connection, it's authenticated traffic).

Comment: I understood that i have to create a vpc access connector and cloud run which will pass my request to the vpc but how will cloud run know which ip I want to hit using cloud task. Do i need to write any program in cloud run for that.  Do u have any link for that because i dont have much knowledge about cloud run

Comment: In fact, Cloud Task will invoke Cloud Run with a body message. The body message is a wrapper of your target request: URL (with your private IP), headers, body, HTTP verb,... Like that your Cloud Run service is agnostic of the destination. Or, you can do a Cloud Run proxy that take the request in entry, simply replace the Cloud Run domain name by the private IP, and forward the request. This time, your Cloud Run service MUST know the target IP in its configuration (env var for instance)